# RedirectToAction usage in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to post some questions about `ASP.Net MVC`. I am not familiar with web developing, But I was assigned to the web part of a project. We are doing the following: first, we create `get` & `set` properties for the person data:

```
public class Person
{
    public int personID {get;set;}
    public string personName {get;set;}
    public string nric {get;set;}
}
```

and after login, we put the data in a class `Person` object and we use `RedirectToAction` like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("profile","person",new { personID = Person.personID});
```

It's working normally, but the parameter are shown in the URL. How can I hide them and also
can I hide the action name? Guide me the right way with some examples, please.

Comment: I think if you don't want the parameter to be seen in the URL you should POST it in a FORM. Then you still have access to it in FormCollection but people won't see it in URL.
But I am also new to all this.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The parameter are shown in the URL because that is what the third parameter to `RedirectToAction` is - the route values.

The default route is `{controller}/{action}/{id}`

So this code:

```
return RedirectToAction("profile","person",new { personID = Person.personID});
```

Will produce the following URL/route:

**/Person/Profile/123**

If you want a cleaner route, like this (for example):

**/people/123**

Create a new route:

```
routes.MapRoute("PersonCleanRoute",
                "people/{id}",
                new {controller = "Person", action = "Profile"});
```

And your URL should be clean, like the above.

Alternatively, you may not like to use ID at all, you can use some other unique identifier - like a nickname.

So the URL could be like this:

**people/rpm1984**

To do that, just change your route:

```
routes.MapRoute("PersonCleanRoute",
                    "people/{nickname}",
                    new {controller = "Person", action = "Profile"});
```

And your action method:

```
public ActionResult Profile(string nickname)
{

}
```

And your RedirectToAction code:

```
return RedirectToAction("profile","person",new { nickname = Person.nickname});
```

Is that what your after?

Comment: so,there is no way to hide parameters?actually we don't want to show any parameter at url. :(

Comment: @Chong - of course you can hide parameters, it just depends on the URL. what url do you *want* then? give me an example URL.

Comment: if you don't want any parameters, just do `return RedirectToAction("profile","person");` But that will produce `/person/profile` which doesn't really make sense as a URL - which is why im asking for you to give me an example of a URL you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply friend,i want to show like this "Person/Profile" without parameter.i mean i will pass paramter,but,don't want to show at URL. regards Chong

Comment: how can you pass parameter without showing it in URL?? where are you going to pass parameter? i think your getting confused. this is not a method in code - this is HTTP, there are parameters and form post values.

Comment: ok friend,so,how i pass parameter to another controller's action?
for example,i have login controller and after login i will pass login information such as personid to Person Controller and it 
will show person profile.How i do?sorry for poor my english.now i use this way,In account controller 
"return RedirectToAction("profile","person",new { personID = Person.personID});",and it calls profile action of person controller.Then,i load person data from database on PersonID that i pass.But,i don't want to show parameter at URL.How i do in asp.net mvc?. regards Chong

Comment: @Chong - i think your getting confused as to the use of `RedirectToAction`. In Web-forms (regular ASP.NET) speak - it basically does a "Response.Redirect("www.somewhere.com")". In other words, a HTTP redirect. Which is what you should be doing. So you need to think about where you are redirecting - you need some sort of identifier to grab the user - this is a *redirect* - you need to pass information via the URL. Pass through the ID or some other identifier. An alternative - if you're using Forms Authentication - you can get the user info from the forms auth ticket.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want the parameter to be shown in the address bar you will need to persist it somewhere on the server between the redirects. A good place to achieve this is `TempData`. Here's an example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TempData["nickname"] = Person.nickname;
    return RedirectToAction("profile", "person");
}
```

And now on the Profile action you are redirecting to fetch it from `TempData`:

```
public ActionResult Profile()
{
    var nickname = TempData["nickname"] as string;
    if (nickname == null)
    {
        // nickname was not found in TempData.
        // this usually means that the user directly
        // navigated to /person/profile without passing
        // through the other action which would store
        // the nickname in TempData
        throw new HttpException(404);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Under the covers `TempData` uses `Session` for storage but it will be automatically evicted after the redirect, so the value could be used only once which is what you need: store, redirect, fetch.

Comment: True, could use this. But do you really wanted to be serializing/de-serializing (assuming non-In proc session) on a single redirect? If he's using forms auth he can fetch the user info from the ticket anyway.

Comment: thanks for all of your replies,my question is TempData gone after refresh the page and i got error.how can i handle this?

Comment: If you read “TempData” by using the “Peek” method it will persist for the next request.
stringstr = TempData.Peek("Td").ToString();
Refer to the following article for more TempData details:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818493/MVC-Tempdata-Peek-and-Keep-confusion

Answer (score 1):

this may be solution of  problem when TempData gone after refresh the page :-

when first time you get TempData  in action method set it in a ViewData & write check as below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TempData["nickname"] = Person.nickname;
    return RedirectToAction("profile", "person");
}
```

now on the Profile action :

```
public ActionResult Profile()
{
    var nickname = TempData["nickname"] as string;

    if(nickname !=null)
        ViewData["nickname"]=nickname;

    if (nickname == null && ViewData["nickname"]==null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(404);
    }
    else
    {
        if(nickname == null)
            nickname=ViewData["nickname"];
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Temp data is capable of handling single subsequent request. Hence, value gone after refresh the page. To mitigate this issue, we can use Session variable also in this case.  Try below:

```
public ActionResult Index(Person _person)
{
    Session["personNickName"] = _person.nickName;
    return RedirectToAction("profile", "person");
}
```

And in "profile" actionmethod:

```
public ActionResult profile()
{
    Person nickName=(Person)Session["personNickName"];
    if(nickName !=null)
    {
    //Do the logic with the nickName
    }
}
```