# Redirect 301 to another action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC Action:

```
public virtual ActionResult Show(Int32 id, String slug) {

} // Show
```

How can I, inside Show, redirect to another action?

I need to fire the 301 redirect HTTP Error to inform that the old url should be replaced by the new url.

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RedirectToActionPermanent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoactionpermanent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

That said, it is important to know that a response status 301 will make browsers to never ask for the original location again. For a simple redirection (302) use [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Both methods are used basically in the same way. In [this StackOVerflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362751/redirecttoaction-usage-in-asp-net-mvc) there are some excellent examples.