# Redirect to view with parameter doesn't work (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: view, parameters, controller, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to redirect a page with few parameters. However, if I try to do it by returning `RedirectToAction()`, the page will not work. Here is the code:

Controller `Home`, Action `Display`:

```
public IActionResult Display()
{
     return RedirectToAction("Display", new
        {
            token = "2a4d237b-e2db-4ffe-ae42-787ae4e7566c",
            id = "abcdefgh",
            display = "Default"
        });
}
```

View

```
  <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Display">Link</a>
```

If I return `View()` in the `Display()` method in the Home controller, that wotks fine the page is loaded.

```
public IActionResult Display()
{
     return View(); //this works
}
```

Comment: You are re-directing to the same action on the same controller, stack overflow exception?

Make a second method that takes that parameters that you specified, then return the view from that one.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want to achieve. If you want to redirect to an action in the same controller, you need to specify the name of your action that returns the view. 
In your code above, you are redirecting to the same action. Have a look at this Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4362800)

Comment: Problem is that when I redirect to same controller but with parameters. However I figured out a way: in the View I mention the parameters to the route <a asp-route-token=@Model.Token asp-route-meetingid=@Model.MeetingId asp-route-displayName="default"/> and in the controller i just return the View().